# Should a user ask a question he already knows the answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138238/pip-regular-expression-search/) with an open bounty on SO, nothing special about it until I saw the [reputation of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe), 36K, with 2k on python and 487 on django tags.

The question there is :

> Does pip provide a way to find packages by a regex? Or, should I just
>   pipe the results of django- to grep to filter out irrelevant packages?

I'm afraid I'm being unfair, but I do think the op knows the answer and he's trying to achieve something else than a simple answer.

Should a question like this be closed? if so, on which bases?

Comment: Er, the OP explicitly asks *"Does `pip` provide a way to find packages by a regex? Or, should I just pipe the results of `django-` to `grep` to filter out irrelevant packages?"* -- then why do you think the OP knows the answer?

Comment: How is “I suspect (for some reason that I will not tell you) that the user knows the answer” related to “this question should be closed”???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm afraid I'm being unfair, but I do think the op knows the answer and he's trying to achieve something else than a simple answer.

There are multiple ways to solve a problem. Judging by the question and the comments, he's looking for a solution that is different from what he already knows. In this specific case, I know I would like it if I could tell `pip` to filter by regex instead of having to pass its output to `grep`.

**SO actually explicitly provides for OPs to post questions whose answer they already know.** It is not meant only for low reputation users. When you post a question, you have an option to post an answer to it *immediately*. This possibility is there primarily for cases where someone had a problem that they solved while writing their question, or that they figured out without even initially thinking of SO but then realized that their solution would be useful to others.

> Should a question like this be closed? if so, on which bases?

Not if you cannot point out one of the usual list of problems that make a question worthy of being closed. The presumed knowledge of the OP is not such a reason.

Comment: I choose your answer because you explained that: **"SO actually explicitly provides for OPs to post questions whose answer they already know."**, I up voted all others because they provide chunks of the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

No, such a question should *not* be closed based on the reputation and the alleged knowledge of the OP.

Questions are meant to be helpful to more than one person. This question meets that criteria.

You close posts based on their content *alone*. The post isn't off-topic; it is not unclear, nor is it too broad or primarily opinion based. It is not a duplicate, nor is it asking for a recommendation, lacking specific information, etc.

Questions are *never* off-topic based solely on suspected ulterior motives.

Answer (score 9):

Reputation is a measure of trust (by the community) not a measure of knowledge.

Besides there are different specialisations. One could be a C++ guru struggeling with c#. And even a guru doesn't know anything about the subject.

But the most important reason not to close the question is that SE is content oriented, not user oriented. So there is no need to base your action on the user, base your action on the content.

Comment: I agree with the part **"base your action on the content"** but it's clearly not the case of **"One could be a C++ guru struggeling with c#"**

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely not. A question is closed because it is bad, not because of the user who wrote it.

I sometimes ask questions I know the answer to just to get a second opinion, or to promote good resources (Everyone in the PHP room know I offer fat bounties for exceptional answers the instant I see them).

Not all questions are asked because the OP needs the answer to solve a problem he could not.

---

### TL;DR

If the question is good, no point in closing it. Regardless of who asked it, how or why.

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily.

Imagine that the OP knows something interesting and wants to share it with the community.
Then s/he posts a question and gives the answer too, marking it as accepted and marking it as Community Wiki.

I saw this done by a highly rewarded member (Iaalto) about a (SQLite) recurring question, in order to provide an answer once and for all.

Comment: There isn't even a direct need to mark it CW. If you contribute good content, you deserve all the rep.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the others above me. There is no problem with the question itself. If you check the comments it turns out that the **OP** asked this question for a reason:

> *another user:* Is there any reason you don't want to pipe the pip search results into
> grep?
>
> *@another user* if pip doesn't support it, or there are no third-party packages that can do this, then I am ok with pipe+grep option. Thanks.

It turns out that the **OP** is looking for better ways to do something. I would go so far to say that in this case you can edit the question itself to contain this information because a lot of people doesn't read comments.

Answer (score -6):

No, strongly disagree for putting unnecessary noise in stackoverflow (SOF) database. As far as user's question has a different perspective, one *must* not post a question for which an answer is known or is already available in SOF. Even if a question is posted, it must be related with previous post.

Whereas SOF must build a logic to identify such defaulters and should punish by giving some negative scores.

Comment: So long as each of the posts are independently of good quality, it is *not* noise.  It is adding a quality question with a quality answer.  **That is what this site is all about**.  When it's done well, it's a great thing.  Of course, it's very hard to do well; most people are pretty bad at asking questions they know the answer to, and answers to poor questions tend to have problems as a result, but for those capable of posting quality content despite these inherent difficulties, there is nothing wrong with their contributions.

Comment: @Servy - I am trying to answer original question where my opinion is rigid that somebody should not ask a question if answer is already known and should only ask if user thinks there are more correction required for same answer. I am not commenting on quality of answers as noise in this particular post.

Comment: You open your post by saying that all self answered questions are noise.  This is of course wrong; they are not all noise.  They can be quite useful.  Your statement is also strictly opposed to the site's policy, which states that it is entirely appropriate to answer your own question or even ask a question that you already know the answer to.

Comment: I get your point here, All self answers are noise was clearly not my intention, whereas I have posted/answered to my question in my older posts (when I had an answer to my posted question, I have added an answer in SOF). There was a verbiage issue where it seems it was presenting a different view all together. Updated my post.

Comment: Posting a question that is a duplicate of another question isn't helpful, that's correct.  How is that in any way related to a self answered question?  Self answered questions should be closed as duplicates, if there are duplicates, just like any other question.  If they're not a duplicate, and there are many that aren't, then what problem do you have with them?

Comment: I believe you did not look at my post, I clearly meant User must relate to a previous post. that means first user must try searching in SOF and if an answer is not found user must post a question ( and if possible answer as well when he get to know the answer, that shows his wisdom and positivity towards sharing knowledge).

Other than this just posting questions which are unnecessary duplicates of previous post and are not related just add unnecessary  noise for users who are actually seeking for an answer. I will prefer in that case user must comment/answer on previous existing post.

Comment: This isn't about duplicate posts at all.  This is about self answered questions.  The fact that someone is answering their own question doesn't mean it is a duplicate.  As I said, if the self answered question happens to be a duplicate, then it's not a good question and should be closed.  If it isn't a duplicate, then what problem do you have with it?  You seem to be equating self answering with duplicate posts.  There is no correlation there.

Comment: I am not relating these two context but was answering my original question 

"Should a user ask a question he already knows the answer?"

And this question is not about "self answered questions" rather its about "1. duplicate questions" (if a previous question already exists) or about "2. fresh question" ( where user is aware of answer and wants to share it with everybody)

I am in favor of point 2 but not in favor of 1.