# Should I ask a question that is meant to verify my assumption?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

Should I ask a question that I'm pretty much sure that I know the answer?

For example:

In my own question (A confession :p) [of Python equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323208/python-what-is-the-equivalent-of-php) I'm pretty sure of the answer of the question is "no". However, I'm not really sure if my assumption is correct. I mean, what if a operator does exist?

So, should I ask a question when I'm pretty much sure that I know the answer?

PS: Ironically, I'm pretty much sure of the answer, but I'm honestly not sure about this one. (Contradict ?)

PS: The difference of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251451/should-a-user-ask-a-question-he-already-knows-the-answer) is that on that question, we are *assumning* that the OP actually knows the answer. Here, *I* am pretty much sure of the answer.

Comment: See also [What can be done to improve moderation of self-answered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137353/what-can-be-done-to-improve-moderation-of-self-answered-questions)

Comment: But I'm not sure of the answer, that's the point. In using that feature, I'm sure of the answer. And take the python equivalent. It will be odd if the answer is just a simple "NO". (Even though it is the truth)

Comment: NO would be a low quality answer but No, with an explantion why that operator doesn't exist can be valueable.

Comment: I have changed your title a little so it doesn't come off as asking things that you know already but more to get verification you're understanding the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

It entirely depends on the question you're asking. If the question itself is good for the site, (fits its scope, is not a duplicate, etc.) then whether or not you are aware of the answer doesn't really matter. Heck, if you're absolutely certain of the answer, there is even the option to immediately answer it yourself.

So that's really the only matter of concern: is the question good enough for the site.