# Asking a question to which you already know the answer for tip/Q&A purposes

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I think this is slightly different from [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251451/should-a-user-ask-a-question-he-already-knows-the-answer):

Quite often I have an amazing piece of functionality that I'm not sure everyone knows about and [I can't find any direct reference to it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read_clipboard) on Stack Overflow.

I'm always tempted to ask a question to which the answer is the top tip I want to share with the world, as follows:

> Q: When people post their `DataFrame`s to a SO question, how can I get
>   the data into Python to begin debugging?
>
> ```
> In []: df
>
> Out[]: 
>        A      B      C
> 0  False  False  False
> 1   True  False  False
> 2  False  False  False
> ```

To which my answer would be:

> A: If you copy the data to the clipboard, the data library Pandas has
>   function `read_clipboard` which will load the copied data into a
>   `DataFrame`.

Should I post this question although I already know (at least one) answer? Should I then immediately answer it myself, or let others take the glory and act surprised and impressed (which makes everyone feel great)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  We want good questions and answers on here.  It is quite possible someone has searched for this, couldn't find anything nut didn't ask as they are not a registered user.

There is even a feature built into SO just for this.  When you go to ask a question there is a check mark asking:

> Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

If you check that then an answer box comes up and you can answer your own question to spread this wonderful information.

[image]

So go ahead and post.  If you want to hold off on answering until you get other answers that is your prerogative but remember that SO thrives because of high quality content and if your content can make it better then you should add it.

If you really want to make people fell warm and fuzzy you could always offer a bounty on it as extra incentive.

Comment: Great idea for the bounty.  You would have to wait 2 days, but that's still a great plan.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. [You've emboldened me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-dataframe-from-stackoverflow-into-python)!